# How to show 5 images in a 2 row slider with bxslider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, carousel, bxslider

I am trying to make an image slider with bxslider. I want to make it a 2 row slider with 5 images showing in each row. The problem is when I add all the code to HTML, CSS and JavaScript everything falls apart

I have tried to make a slider on the left side of the page and add some text on the right side next to the slider but nothing is working. My slider keeps showing my images on one slide in a column and the other slide in a row.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.wraper').bxSlider({
        minSlides: 1,
        maxSlides: 5,
        mode: 'fade',
        adaptiveHeight: true
      });
    });
```

Comment: I dont understand what you want, additionally what does this code u posted has to do with that what u want. Also try using swiper slider

Comment: @Learner I want to position two divs one next to each other with the slider being left and the text right. I also want to create a slider with 2 rows with 5 images in each row. The code i posted is for the bxslider properties.

Comment: you can show 5 images at a time but you cant create 2 diff rows for these images it can be one row only with 5 images

Comment: or in easy words one slide can have one row only with 5 images, if you want i can help you with that

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes please, I would be very happy if You could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `slideWidth` and `mode:'horizontal'` along with the `minSlides` and `maxSlides` to show 5 slides in a single row, although you cant display 2 rows on a single slide, the plugin does not support it.

For a single row with 5 images to be displayed at a time see below

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var a = $('.slider').bxSlider({
    minSlides: 1,
    maxSlides: 5,
    mode: 'horizontal',
    adaptiveHeight: true,
    slideWidth: 100,
    moveSlides: 5,
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/bxslider/4.2.12/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>



<div class="slider">
  <div><img src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/982172572/5070580cca87408d911344542276639c?v=1"></div>
  <div><img src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/982172572/5070580cca87408d911344542276639c?v=1"></div>
  <div><img src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/982172572/5070580cca87408d911344542276639c?v=1"></div>
  <div><img src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/982172572/5070580cca87408d911344542276639c?v=1"></div>
  <div><img src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/982172572/5070580cca87408d911344542276639c?v=1"></div>
  <div><img src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/982172572/5070580cca87408d911344542276639c?v=1"></div>
  <div><img src="https://is1-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple60/v4/0b/b7/73/0bb7737a-db83-87bf-f10e-20d0bed3a496/source/256x256bb.jpg"></div>
</div>
```